# asp dropdownlist from xml geting innnertext of child ele

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, drop-down-menu

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
  <book id="bk101">
    <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
    <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>44.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
    <description>
      An in-depth look at creating applications
      with XML.
    </description>
  </book>
  <book id="bk102">
    <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
    <title>Midnight Rain</title>
    <genre>Fantasy</genre>
    <price>5.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
    <description>
      A former architect battles corporate zombies,
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen
      of the world.
    </description>
  </book>...

<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="XmlDataSource2" DataTextField="id" DataValueField="id">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            DataFile="~/App_Data/XMLFile1.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>
```

right now the dropdownlist shows me the books id
but i need to get the author names 
and i cant get it to work 
can anyone plez help me out ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use XSLT to transform the data.
see this link how to do it:
[Using XSLT files with the new XMLDataSource control](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/pages/431322.aspx)

Comment: love u long time :)) thx alott i was rdy to bang my head on the screen trying to get this to work :)

Comment: if it helps you I'm very happy. and if you can please mark my answer as the answer and vote to it. thanks too.